# Is it possible to skip few called value while calling the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
def get_plot(z1,z2,c1,c2,col,a1,a2,b1,b2,title):
    ax[z1][z2] = plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(c1,c2),colspan =col)
    ax[z1][z2].plot(a1, b1, linewidth=2, color= ([0.37,0.23,0.37]), marker = 'o')
```

I have multiple plots, in which I don't have values for a2 and b2.
Can some tell me how to skip the appropriate arguments and `plot` call?

Comment: You can make a parameter optional if you put a default value for it. For example, `a1=None,a2=None` would set those values to None if you don't provide them. It looks like you need those values in the function, but maybe you can find a default that works for you.

Comment: are you just asking about `if` statements?

Comment: @mindfolded That doesn't work, just to let you know

Comment: @EricDsilva It works, just maybe not for you. Do you know what a2 and b2 are typically? Is there a value besides `None` that you could supply that will let it get past the `plot()` functions without failing? For example, try `a2=0` and `b2=0`.

Comment: @SamMason  --> get_plot(z1,z2,c1,c2,col,a1,a2,b1,b2,title)
I just want to skip a2 and b2 if I am calling the function again

Comment: @EricDsilva I'd suggest going through a Python tutorial to understand how "conditional statements" work

Comment: @mindfolded -> while calling the function get_plot(z1,z2,c1,c2,col,a1,a2,b1,b2,title) I just want to skip a2 and b2

Comment: I know what you want @EricDsilva, did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @mindfolded That doesn't work
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: @EricDsilva Move them to the end.

Comment: @EricDsilva it doesn't make sense to have required arguments come after required ones, your option is to either make everything after the optional ones also optional as in `get_plot(z1,z2,c1,c2,col,a1,a2=None,b1=None,b2=None,title=None)` or have all of your optional arguments come last `get_plot(z1,z2,c1,c2,col,a1,b1,title,a2=None,b2=None)`

Comment: `def get_plot(z1,z2,c1,c2,col,
             a1=None, a2=None,
             b1=None, b2=None, title=""):

    ax[z1][z2] = plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(c1,c2),colspan =col)
    ax[z1][z2].plot(a1, b1, linewidth=2, color= ([0.37,0.23,0.37]), marker = 'o')
    if a2 is not None and b2 is not None:
        ax[z1][z2].plot(a2, b2, linewidth=2, color = ([0.44,0.64,0.69]), marker = 'o')`

Comment: @RyanHaining I got that, you can check the above function I changed something like that. Is it possible to tell me how the best way to re-write this function. right now its littlebit complex and difficult to understand

Comment: @EricDsilva it seems like you might want to change `a1, b1` and `a2, b2` to accept a list of (x, y) pairs instead? then you could pass 0 or more pairs instead of one or two pairs, but not sure what you're goal is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this solve your problem?

```
def get_plot(z1,z2,c1,c2,col,
             a1=None, a2=None,
             b1=None, b2=None, title=""):

    ax[z1][z2] = plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(c1,c2),colspan =col)
    ax[z1][z2].plot(a1, b1, linewidth=2, color= ([0.37,0.23,0.37]), marker = 'o')
    if a2 is not None and b2 is not None:
        ax[z1][z2].plot(a2, b2, linewidth=2, color = ([0.44,0.64,0.69]), marker = 'o')
```

Your existing calls will work just fine.  However, when you're missing a2 and b2 values, you'll want something more like this to call the function:

```
get_plot(z1, z2, c1, c2, col, a1=local_a1, b1=local_b1, title=plot_title)
```

Once you get to an omitted argument, you must give the names for everything remaining.
In this example, you wouldn't need the `a1=`, but I left it there for ease of reading.

Comment: Any thoughts what I are missing here
def get_plot(m,n,c1,c2,col,
            m1,m2=None,m3=None,
            n1,n2=None,n3=None,
            lab1=None,lab2=None,lab3=None,title):
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument

Comment: Yes, exactly what it says: you have arguments with default values, and then one with no default value.  That one is `title` at the end.

Comment: Gotcha, Thanks a lot

Comment: Any other way I can write this function in a more simplified manner?

Comment: "More simplified" in what fashion?  If you're trying to simplify the signature (the `def` line), you can put all of the arguments into a list or a dict and unpack them in the function with the `*` operator, such as `def get_plot(*arg_dict):`

Comment: Can you please give me a small example, I am new to python getting a little bit confused here
I want to if there is any other way to write above whole function

Comment: An example of *what*, exactly?  This is not a tutorial site.  "Any other way to write this" is far too broad.  The `*` operator is documented well in many other questions and tutorials.

Comment: I know that it's not a tutorial site. you are one of the professional and I am a beginner that is a reason I ask help because I don't know what the heck _*_ do?

Comment: @EricDsilva: what Prune is saying is that the site should not be used for tutoring or mentoring. If you need to read on the basics, then there are plenty of tutorials easily available that you should avail yourself of.